# Compute all steps toward local extrema for multivariable function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to create a Mathematica script which takes as input a function of two variables, and in turn computes all the necessary steps (finding roots of the first partial derivatives, checking the relevant 2nd order conditions) in a verbose manner (e.g. show all the partial derivatives) to find local extremal points.

Most of this is straightforward, my biggest problem is how to reuse the roots found by `Solve[]` in successive computations. I started like this:

```
f[x_,y_] :=  y^3 -3 x^2 y
dfx[x_,y_]:=D[f[x,y],x]
dfy[x_,y_]:=D[f[x,y],y]
dfxx[x_,y_]:=D[f[x,y],x, x]
dfyy[x_,y_]:=D[f[x,y],y, y]
dfx[x_,y_]:=D[f[x,y],x]
dfxy[x_,y_]:=D[f[x,y],x,y]
dff[x_,y_]:=dfxx[x,y]*dfyy[x,y]-(dfxy[x,y])^2
Solve[{dfx[x,y]==0, dfy[x,y]==0},{x,y}]
Apply[dff, %]
Evaluate[dff[%]]
```

I am stuck here, any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
solns = Solve[{dfx[x, y] == 0, dfy[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]
CheckSoln[soln_] := 
  (
    hessianDet = ReplaceAll[dff[x, y], soln];
    Print["First order condition solution: ", soln, 
        "; has Hessian determinant=", hessianDet
    ];
  )
Map[CheckSoln, solns]
```

Answer (score 7):

It might be slightly easier if we use immediate rather than delayed assignments for those derivatives. (If you want something more general i.e. to handle arbitrary functions f, it will not be too hard to modify using locally scoped variables.) I use a new function that has multiple critical points.

```
f[x_, y_] := y^4 - y^3 - 3 x^2 y + x^4
dfx[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], x];
dfy[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], y];
dfxx[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], x, x];
dfyy[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], y, y];
dfxy[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], x, y];
dff[x_, y_] = dfxx[x, y]*dfyy[x, y] - (dfxy[x, y])^2;
solns = {x, y} /. Solve[{dfx[x, y] == 0, dfy[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}];
realsolns = Select[solns, FreeQ[#, Complex] &]
```

Here are the solution points.

```
Out[87]= {{0, 0}, {0, 3/4}, {-(3/2), 3/2}, {3/2, 3/2}}
```

Now can apply the second derivative Jacobian to each as below.

```
In[88]:= jacs = dff @@@ realsolns

Out[88]= {0, -(81/8), 243, 243}
```

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research